# How to check session for many levels in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three levels of users in my website, Managers,employees and normal users.  Each of them in different table in my database.

I created a log in form using login tool. Then I created connection and sessions.They work fine.

now my question is what is the best way to check the session in all pages (if it is manger, employee or user). it would be more useful if there is example :)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What have you tried? Note that there is no single best solution to a vast majority of problems.

Comment: for example one of the solution is to set three sessions one for managers another for employees and the last for users. then to write in each page if session is not manager or whatever then redirect him to login page. but I now this way is not efficient so I need help.

Comment: I would suggest Unit / Integration tests. If we don't want to go that deep and stick with black box testing, use the developer tools and check the cookie details (eventually session is a cookie)

Comment: @LJ It doesn't sound like they meant "test" as in "make sure the code works" but rather "test" as in "check user's authorization"

Comment: you are right I didn't mean testing.  I want the best code for session if I have deferent level of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty traditional and simple, you could use [this tried and true method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649204.aspx).

Essentially you would use the [UserData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the authentication ticket to store the current users' roles.  You can then obtain the data at any time from the current thread's [principal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx).